# media print doesn't apply style on chrome, but in firefox works perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have this js function:

```
function print(title, htmlPrint) {
   var w = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=750');
   w.document.title = title;
   w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" />');
   w.document.write(htmlPrint);
   w.document.close(); // needed for chrome and safari
   w.print();
   w.close();
   return false;
}
```

and in css I have something like this:

```
@media print, screen{ 
.....
}
```

In firefox works as intended: shows title & content, in chrome it just shows me the title and a blank page (the same when I print).

**I've tried** also with `@media print{}` or `@media all{}` and still doesn't work.

**I've tried** also to add `media="print"` in `<link... />`, doing that it loads the css, but doesn't apply any css to the page.

**I've tried** also to change the function and use `w.document.head.innerHtml` and `w.document.body.innerHtml` - still nothing, has the same behavior as `.write()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me:

First I had to get the full path of the css file and set the media print in the link tag.

```
if (/chrome/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
     w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + location.protocol + '//' + location.host + (new String(location.pathname.substring(0, location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/")))) + '/print.css" media="print" />');
}else{
     w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" />');
}
```

Then it still didn't work properly and I just found out that the `w.close()`  makes problems to chrome.

```
if (/chrome/i.test(navigator.userAgent) === false) {
    w.close();
}
```